# Path for persisting files between Capistrano deployments in a Ruby app

Tags: ruby, linux, file-io, filesystems, capistrano

Where is the proper path for creating files using Ruby on a *nix environment?  The files must persist between restarts and releases. Obviously using the project path doesn't work as Capistrano will create a new folder for each push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano has a `system` directory created by default that should be linked to the `shared/system` directory at the root of your release path. This will persist between deployments.

You should put anything there that is not specific to your deployment, for example, attached files or other user uploads.

In your version control system you should be sure to not deploy this directory as to avoid packaging up your development-specific content. Generally it should be ignored, not included in your version control.

Comment: Are you talking about the public/system link that's created under the project folder?